# Set the access rights to a project directory on sourceforge

Tags: upload, sourceforge, rights

Let's say I am the administrator of some project on sf.net. I want to
add a new user as member of a project, and to grant him
rights to create files in some directory.
I added a user as member of a project, but it didn't have a
possibility to create/delete files/directories.

If someone has experience in a similar question, prompt to me please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to ask this question on either #sourceforge on irc.freenode.net, or create a support ticket at https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/new/ or email the support staff at sfnet_ops@geek.net

What you're describing shouldn't happen, so you need to report it as a problem. However, it *could* just take a little time for the necessary permissions to get applied, so it might depend on how close together the two events are.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on SourceForge's latest platform i.e Allura, here are the steps you can try.

1) Log in to SF 
2) Click on Admin tab 
3) Click on User Permissions

You should be able to add users, create group and manage permission for group.